# How to do Bitwise XOR in mysql column

Tags: mysql, bit, xor

I have table with a column which has binary values.

Table looks like this

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tDataSyncUpdate;
CREATE TABLE tDataSyncUpdate
(
  _ID        INT      AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  Updated_On DATETIME DEFAULT now(),
  Update_Bit BIGINT   DEFAULT 0000000000000000
);
```

I have to do bitwise XOR on Update_Bit column.

I am doing something like this,

```
SELECT lpad(BIT_XOR(Update_Bit), 16, '0') AS Update_Bit FROM tDataSyncUpdate
```

But it is not giving me the expected result. I need to get the values after the bitwise XOR.

This is the data i have in table

```
1   2020-01-07 06:26:01 100000000000000
2   2020-01-07 06:27:32 101000000000000
3   2020-01-07 06:28:02 100000000000000
4   2020-01-07 06:28:41 110000000000000
5   2020-01-07 06:30:07 100000000000000
6   2020-01-07 06:31:06 000100000000000
```

I need to get the value like this 1111000000000000.

Please help me out solving this problem.

I need something like this.

[image]

But i won't be having only 2 values to compare with, i will be having multiple values.

Comment: Well, what is the *wrong* value you get?

Comment: Yes i get something like this 92270486497792

Comment: Your values in the table need to be the integer equivalent of the binary, e.g. `16384` instead of `100000000000000`

Comment: See also [binary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11035285/convert-a-binary-to-decimal-using-mysql)

Comment: @Adder Each byte here indicates a switch (Example role access, first 4 bits indicates Add, Update, Delete and Read). If 1 then has access else no access. So one can have multiple roles so i have to use BIT OR on these so that i can get the actual access on the object for the user.

Comment: BIT_XOR or BIT_OR? They are very different. Regarding the datatype of the column `Update_Bit`. It should either be binary, or you need to set the value to an integer having the corresponding bits set in its binary representation. The integer cannot simply be `10010000000000000`. You do understand how bits and integers relate, do you?

Comment: I got the solution. I need to first conver the `bigint` to base 2 and then i need to perform the bit_xor or bit_or operation and then again i need to convert the resulted value to binary using `bin` function. Thanks for the suport @Adder